# Push notifications ti.App resume event handler (titanium)

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium

Here is my code

```
function registerPushNotifications() {

    Titanium.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
        types : [Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE, Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT],
        success : function(e) {
            var deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
            Ti.API.info("Push notification device token is: " + deviceToken);
            Ti.API.info("Push notification types: " + Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationTypes);
            Ti.API.info("Push notification enabled: " + Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationsEnabled);

            Ti.API.error("device Token is: " + e.deviceToken);

            //return device Token to store in Model.
            return e.deviceToken;
        },
        error : function(e) {
            Ti.API.info("Error during registration: " + e.error);
        },
        callback : function(e) {
            // called when a push notification is received.
            //var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            var data = e.data;

            var badge = data.badge;
            if (badge > 0) {
                Titanium.UI.iPhone.appBadge = badge;
            }
            var message = data.message;
            if (message != '') {
                var my_alert = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                    title : '',
                    message : message
                });
                my_alert.show();
            }

            Ti.App.addEventListener('resume', function() {

alert('do another event if coming from background');


        }
    });

};
```

Depending on whether the push notification comes from the background or foreground I want to run different events.

I have tried

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('resume', function() {
```

but this fires EVERYTIME I return to the app from the background (the event handlers will be stacked every time a push notification to sent and fires all of them). As opposed to only executing that part of the callback code for push notifications that have come in from the background.

How do I know if the push notification came from the background or whilst app is running? cheers

Update:

Solved it.

If you check the call back object, you will find IsBackground as a property to check where the push notification came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Check JSON object of callback for the isBackground boolean event.

If 1 it means that it was called from the background, if 0, this means that it wasn't.